# How to target Ajax Loaded Elements in Jquery Load Function

Tags: jquery

I'm loading in some HTML content like this:

```
$('#scores').load('scores.php #scores');
```

Note that It is a requirement that I target a specific part of scores.php (as there is other text surrounding the area I'm trying to target.

However the HTML generated by the load function is not targetable with JQuery.

For example if the #scores html is like this:

```
<div class="score">2335</div>
```

The JQuery Event listener doesn't pickup on this:

```
$('.score').click(function(event){
  /* This doesn't work */
  alert('this alert never fires if the click event listener is an ajax generated item.');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not reactivating the .click event after the data has been loaded into the page. I've had this problem myself.

The two solutions I've come up with are to use the success callback on the ajax to reactivate the click event (ensuring that it'll always be live after it's loaded) or to use the .on("click", function()) instead, because it'll always exist.

edit: changed live to on. force of habit.

Comment: the .live() worked for me.  I think it is the updated version of the .on methods mentioned below see: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: actually, `.live` is depreciated now. `.on` is the replacement.

Comment: @Talon. Yeah `live` shouldn't be used since *jQuery 1.4.4* we are on **1.7.1** this days...

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate event. like `on` for new jQuery versions (1.7+).

```
$('#containerId').on('click','.score', function(event){
  /* This DOES work NOW*/
});
```

`containerId` should be the closest **static** element (exist when the DOM is ready.) that holds the `.score` elements.

If you use older version of jQuery choose the right function:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

`on` [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) about delegate events:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: Are you sure that "selector" is mandatory? According the documentation is optional. There may be a difference, but I'm missing the point of passing it as parameter for "on"

Comment: @ClaudioRedi. Yes I'm sure. _"If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element."_